# Why was this question automatically deleted by the Community Bot on 08/13/2022?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, deleted-questions, community-user

Why was this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4216490) automatically deleted by the Community Bot on 08/13/2022?

(And for no apparent good reason, that is!)

I tried voting to undelete, but it says I can no longer vote to undelete, because I have already voted to undelete, which is weird.

Also, there has been an activity in the question for the past $30$ days, so I would not really call it *an automatic deletion by the system due to inactivity*.

What is going on?

Comment: I restored the post.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @quid!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you know, some questions are automatically deleted. Indeed, this also happened in this case.

Specifically it seems to fall under 10 in that thread [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

> 10. The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions older than 365 days on main (non-meta) sites, that have a score of zero (or have a score of 1 and the owner's account is deleted), have fewer than 1.5 views per day on average, and fewer than two comments. (RemoveAbandonedQuestions)

Note that it was deleted just a little over a year past after it was posted;  this script does not run daily, as far as I know, so some shift is expected.

That said, I agree it is rather surprising to have a recently edited question *with a bounty* deleted in this way.

Indeed, it might be a known bug, according to [Question with an active bounty was mistakenly deleted by the Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359901/question-with-an-active-bounty-was-mistakenly-deleted-by-the-roomba) which mentions [Prevent questions with bounty from being auto-deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247970/prevent-questions-with-bounty-from-being-auto-deleted) that is an implemented feature request.

Comment: What happened actually was - I did delete the question around a year ago, with the intention of undeleting it "when the right time comes" (i.e. when I have made sure that there are no logical loopholes).  At any rate, I do agree that it might be a known bug.  (I will read those posts you have linked to later when time permits.)  Thanks a lot, @quid.